# RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage messages received out of order

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage to send messages on Android, but they seem to be coming through out of order. The [concept document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) states:

> Reliable messaging. With reliable messaging, data delivery, integrity, and ordering are guaranteed.

I'm breaking up a large packet into multiple 1400 byte messages and sending each one with sendReliableMessage, which is done in a loop. After that loop, I send another message using sendReliableMessage, but on the receiving device, the last message is coming through before some of the other ones. The code for sending a packet is:

```
public void sendPacket(Packet packet)
{
    try {

        Log.d(getPackageName(), "Sending packet: " + packet.getClass().getSimpleName());

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutpuStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutpuStream);
        outputStream.writeObject(packet);
        byte[] bytes = byteOutpuStream.toByteArray();
        outputStream.close();

        if(m_Participants != null) {
            for (Participant participant : m_Participants) {
                if (participant.getParticipantId().equals(m_LocalParticipantID) == false) {

                    Log.d(getPackageName(), "Sending object size " + bytes.length + " to participant " + participant.getParticipantId());
                    byte[] objectSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(bytes.length).array();
                    int sendResult = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage(m_GoogleClient, this, objectSize, m_RoomID, participant.getParticipantId());
                    Log.d(getPackageName(), "Send object size result: " + sendResult);

                    Log.d(getPackageName(), "Sending packet to " + participant.getParticipantId());
                    int bytesRemaining = bytes.length;
                    if(bytesRemaining <= Multiplayer.MAX_RELIABLE_MESSAGE_LEN)
                    {
                        Log.d(getPackageName(), "Sending full packet " + bytesRemaining + " bytes");
                        sendResult = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage(m_GoogleClient, this, bytes, m_RoomID, participant.getParticipantId());
                        Log.d(getPackageName(), "Send packet result: " + sendResult);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int sentAmount = 0;
                        byte[] bufferToSend = new byte[Multiplayer.MAX_RELIABLE_MESSAGE_LEN];
                        while(bytesRemaining > 0) {
                            int byteCountSent = 0;
                            if(bytesRemaining >= Multiplayer.MAX_RELIABLE_MESSAGE_LEN)
                            {
                                byteCountSent = Multiplayer.MAX_RELIABLE_MESSAGE_LEN;
                                for(int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < byteCountSent; ++byteIndex)
                                {
                                    bufferToSend[byteIndex] = bytes[sentAmount + byteIndex];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                byteCountSent = bytesRemaining;
                                bufferToSend = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, sentAmount, sentAmount + bytesRemaining);
                            }
                            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Sending " + bufferToSend.length + " bytes");
                            sendResult = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage(m_GoogleClient, this, bufferToSend, m_RoomID, participant.getParticipantId());
                            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Send packet result: " + sendResult);

                            bytesRemaining -= byteCountSent;
                            sentAmount += byteCountSent;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What this does is first send a message with the packet size in, then split the packet up if necessary and send that. The log output looks like:

```
First call to sendPacket:

Sending object size 62234 to participant p_CImSt4aNy73IiQEQAQ
Send object size result: 1

Sending packet to p_CImSt4aNy73IiQEQAQ
Sending 1400 bytes
Send packet result: 2
Sending 1400 bytes
Send packet result: 3
Sending 1400 bytes
...
Send packet result: 44
Sending 1400 bytes
Send packet result: 45
Sending 634 bytes
Send packet result: 46

Next call to sendPacket:

Sending packet: StartGamePacket
Sending object size 267 to participant p_CImSt4aNy73IiQEQAQ
Send object size result: 47

Sending packet to p_CImSt4aNy73IiQEQAQ
Sending full packet 267 bytes
Send packet result: 48
```

The receive function is, which gets the 4 byte packet size and then reassembles the packet as the messages come in, looks like:

```
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage realTimeMessage)
{
    try {

        byte[] data = realTimeMessage.getMessageData();
        Log.d(getPackageName(), "onRealTimeMessageReceived: " + data.length + " bytes");

        // Are we expecting a packet?
        if(m_CurrentPacketData == null)
        {
            // Get the packet size
            if(data.length != 4)
            {
                Log.d(getPackageName(), "Error! 4 bytes expected for packet size, got " + data.length);
            }
            else
            {
                int packetSize = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getInt();
                m_CurrentPacketData = new byte[packetSize];
                m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Append the data to the packet
            Log.d(getPackageName(), "Received data of " + data.length + " bytes");
            for(int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < data.length; ++byteIndex)
            {
                m_CurrentPacketData[m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount + byteIndex] = data[byteIndex];
            }
            m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount += data.length;

            // Have we received it all?
            if(m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount == m_CurrentPacketData.length)
            {
                Log.d(getPackageName(), "Full packet received");

                ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(m_CurrentPacketData);
                ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteInputStream);
                Packet packet = (Packet) inputStream.readObject();
                inputStream.close();
                m_ReceivedPackets.add(packet);

                Log.d(getPackageName(), "Packet received: " + packet.getClass().getSimpleName());

                m_CurrentPacketData = null;
                m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount = 0;

                processReceivedPackets();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(getPackageName(), "Still " + (m_CurrentPacketData.length - m_CurrentPacketReceiveCount) + " bytes remaining");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the log on the receiving end looks like this:

```
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 4 bytes
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 60834 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 59434 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 58034 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 56634 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 55234 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 53834 bytes remaining
...
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 17434 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 16034 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 14634 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 13234 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 11834 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 634 bytes
Received data of 634 bytes
Still 11200 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 9800 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 4 bytes
Received data of 4 bytes
Still 9796 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 8396 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 6996 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 267 bytes
Received data of 267 bytes
Still 6729 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 5329 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 3929 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 2529 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
Still 1129 bytes remaining
onRealTimeMessageReceived: 1400 bytes
Received data of 1400 bytes
```

As you can see near the end, the packets are coming in out of order. Has anyone else had issues like this with Real-time multiplayer on Android?

Comment: Can you please share a sample with your solution ? (i.e. "ended up changing the packet structure to contain an ID in the header which is incremented with each packet, so that the receiver can keep track of the order of the packets and reorder the ones which arrive out of order.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you solved that issue?
It looks like implementation does not guarantee the order. So what you might do is to check re callback result (`onRealTimeMessageSent`) for this message id (called token and retuned by `sendReliableMessage`), and only when the result is OK, send the next packet.

Comment: I ended up changing the packet structure to contain an ID in the header which is incremented with each packet, so that the receiver can keep track of the order of the packets and reorder the ones which arrive out of order. It's a bit faster than waiting for confirmation of each packet. I think you're right that there's either a bug in the implementation, or the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: The same problem had occured to me, and after some tests I concluded that `sendReliableMessage` doesn't guarantee that the packets will be delivered in the same order. I just decided to wait for the `onRealTimeMessageSent` callback to enforce an ordering on the sender side.